# Sync Magento2 with UniVerse db

Tags: magento2, database

I am new to Magento. I was able to **retrieve products** from our **UniVerse db** using php COM extension in an upgrade script.

But what I really need to achieve is to implement a system that would sync data between Magento2 website and UniVerse db. If a product's price, let's say, is updated in UniVerse, then this price would be updated in Magento too. And of course if a client orders products from Magento, our UniVerse db should be informed.

I could not find any pre-built connector for this so I think I have to create a custom script for this. I am a bit lost so I would really appreciate if someone would give me advice as to which path to follow.

Should I create webservices for this? (but, webservices rely on http protocol, which is not the case of Uniobjects, am I right?)
Should I create cron jobs for updates in Magento with data from UniVerse ?

Thanks a lot for your help and insights.